# java UnknownHostException

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, unknown-host

I am trying this simple tutorial from oracle : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html (the Example 1 ). Here you have the two classes, [SocketServer.java](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/Code/SocketServer.java) and [SocketClient.java](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/Code/SocketClient.java). When I run the client ( after I started the server), I get "Unknown host: kq6py.eng" in the console. I am on MAC OS X. What should I do? I tried setting the proxy settings in Eclipse but nothing changed.

Comment: Set the hostname to something you can resolve. (Likely localhost if you're running all that on the same machine.)

Comment: Try IP instead of not-existing hostname.

Comment: Yes, that was it! So stupid of me :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written `The listenSocket method first creates a Socket object with the computer name ( kq6py) and port number (4321)`
I doubt you got the same computer name as the example, so you should replace it by **your** computer name.